# While loop user input problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a school exercise where I have to write a program that outputs ‘Odd number’ or ‘Even number’ when a user inputs an integer. Keep looping until user presses Q to stop the program. So far I have this;

```
while(True):
    num= int(input("Enter a number"))
    mod= num % 2
    if (mod > 0):
            print("This is an odd number")
    elif (mod == 0):
            print("This is an even number")
    else:
            print("Bye")
            exit()
```

However, since Q is not an integer, it gives me a ValueError. How should I do this exercise? Thanks

Comment: Don't cast it to an int. Check to see if the value is `'Q'` first.

Answer (score 3):

It is the `int` function that raises the `ValueError`, we can catch it with a `try`-`except` clause:

```
while(True):
    inp = input("Enter a number"))
    if inp == 'Q':
            print("Bye")
    else:
        try:
            num = int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input')
            continue;
        mod= num % 2
        if (mod > 0):
            print("This is an odd number")
        elif (mod == 0):
            print("This is an even number")
```

Nevertheless the code is not really "*Pythonic*". For example you write `mod > 0`, but since here the only two possibilities are `0` and `1` for integers, we know that in that case it is `1`. We do not have to check for `1`, we can check the truthiness.

Another aspect is the `mod == 0` in the `elif`. Since we know that if `mod > 0`, then it means that `mod == 0`, so we can use an `else` instead. Usually one does not write brackets in `if`s and `while`s (unless to change the semantics of the expression that is checked). So we can use:

```
while True:
    inp = input("Enter a number"))
    if inp == 'Q':
        print("Bye")
        exit()
    try:
        num = int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue;
    if num % 2:
        print("This is an odd number")
    else:
        print("This is an even number")
```

Comment: This will not exit just for `Q`, it will exit for any non int.

Comment: Thought: you often use **bold** in your code, I've never seen anyone else do this (at least not regularly), do people like this? could be worth a meta post?

Comment: An `else` clause instead of `exit()` is more readable.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: whether people like it is completely irrelevent. It would convert way too much *adeninetriposhpate* into *adeninediphoshpate* when writing such post. I know that Prolog programmers have used it frequently, and since Prolog is the most minimalistic language I know, I think that is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, I still haven't familiarized myself with the exceptions but I will look more into them now :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `user_input = input()` before I do any things with it.

Here's fixed version:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number")

    if user_input == "Q":
        print("Bye")
        exit()

    num = int(user_input)
    mod = num % 2
    if (mod > 0):
        print("This is an odd number")
    elif (mod == 0):
        print("This is an even number")
```

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. I tend not to use input = input () so I really should start doing that :)